# blade service injection not working Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to inject a controller into my view(blade.php) but it is being outputted as is 
`@inject('problems', 'App\Http\Controllers\DonnerController')`
this line is being printed on the screen, what's wrong here?
My file name is `problems.blade.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found no solution to the problem. I decided to choose a different route since I wanted to share data to my view without any post request sent from page.
I used

### [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)

a better way to share data to views. I took help from laracasts and this [tutorial](http://culttt.com/2014/02/10/using-view-composers-laravel-4/) to implement ViewComposers. I hope it may help any future beginner.